# Event when the user changes font size in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I need to get informed when the user changes the font size in it's browser.

I need it to reposition some elements which have to be relative in one dimension to an anchor inside a text.

So far i haven't found anything and i'm a bit worried that it's not possible. In this case it should be possible to emulate it with a hidden div and some text inside and a script polling for changes of it's width. But i hope someone has a more elegant solution.

**EDIT:**

I implemented the polling thing like following. It's not properly tested on all Browsers but it doesn't depend on browser specific features. use it like $('body').bind('fontResize', function(){...})

```
$(function(){
  $('body').append($('<div id="theFontResizeCaptureDiv">A<br>B<br>C</div>'));
  $('#theFontResizeCaptureDiv').css({visibility: 'hidden', position: 'absolute'});

  window.setInterval(function(){
    var div = $('#theFontResizeCaptureDiv');
    var stored = parseInt(div.attr('c_height'));
    if(isNaN(stored)){ // first run
      div.attr('c_height', div.innerHeight());
    }else if(stored != div.innerHeight()){ // changed
      div.attr('c_height', div.innerHeight());
      $('body').trigger('fontResize');
    }
  }, 200);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect browser font size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739940/detect-browser-font-size)?

Comment: This is a more useful question than the possible dupe.  There are somethings that even with CSS + em + ex you need to code some positionings (I have a DIV which has to be absolutely positioned to work with an external JS library and that absolute position needs to take into account the font sizing of the user).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to an article describing different methods to detect font resizing:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fontresizing/

Answer (score 0):

You can use idea from this file https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries/blob/master/src/ResizeSensor.js

I've incorported it in [jQuery Terminal as jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/blob/1.9.0/js/jquery.terminal.js#L749) and use div with `&nbsp;` and css:

```
.font {
   position: absolute;
   font-size: inherit;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 1em;
   height: 1em;
}
```

that way if parent element, that have position: relative or absolute, change font-size the `.font` element will change size and trigger resizer callback.

You can use this plugin like this:

```
var font = $('<div class="font">&nbsp;</div>').appendTo(self);

font.resizer(function() {
   // font changed size
});
```

where `self` is your parent element, if you need to detect this event on body you can use `'body'` instead.