# How to set a fixed font size/ prevent browser scaling for a specific single element?

Tags: css, font-size

I want the font in my navigation bar to be a fixed size - not affected by browser font size changes. I'm totally fine with the rest of the text being fluid but the design of my site is such that i need the nav bar text to remain the same size no matter what.

Here is an example of what i would LIKE to do. Don't know how this was done. The nav bar on the top right is unaffected by font size increase/decrease. If someone could clue me in it would be greatly appreciated! :)

http://studiogang.net/

Also, I don't want to use an image instead, because the dropdown menu i want won't work with image mapping. Or at least, i'd rather not go down that road.

Comment: Simply set the size in pixels (ie. 12px)? Or do you mean when the user zooms as well?

Comment: They used a background image http://studiogang.net/graphics/nav/top.png - not recommended.  In fact they use images for all the text on that page.  If a user wants / needs to increase the font size, why would you want to deny them that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means 'not affected by browser zoom level changes'...

Comment: The example site is affected by browser zoom level.  The background images get bigger and blurry.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. not talking about zoom here - that works  fine for me. I've tried defining the size in pixels and em. @davidpauljunior i see that they've got a background image. hmmm... but they also have text in the html. Did they layer text on top of the image? This could be something i would want to do.

Comment: They just have the text as an accessibility thing. They use `text-indent: -9999px;` to hide it off the screen.

Comment: Maybe I'm as dense as a diamond, but I have no clue as to what you're going for since setting your font-size in pixels should tackle your problem the way I see it. Perhaps your problem is related to (the absence of) certain system fonts?

Comment: @ravb79 lol im talking about increasing font size in the preference of your browser. not zooming in. going into your preferences and increasing or decreasing the font size

Comment: @user2981170 Okay, then maybe you should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739940/detect-browser-font-size - if you get it to work, you could resize the font percentually depending on the user's browser settings.

Comment: Cool i'll check it out. I still find it weird they use text along with an image in the example site. Is there any advantage to this? How is this an accessibility thing? @davidpauljunior

Comment: Because without the actual text there, it would be a list that contained nothing, which is not a very good menu.  Screen readers won't tell that there's a background image that's acting as a menu item.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="navbar" style="font-size:14px">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using text-size-adjust:

```
 -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
 -ms-text-size-adjust:none;
 -moz-text-size-adjust:none;
 text-size-adjust:none;
```

It only works on mobile though.

Apart from that I think the only option is to make your layout working well on different zoom levels.

Answer (score 0):

We should not use this, because of accessibility issues. If you set fonts to "fixed" size, then those who have system font to 200% or perhaps browser-zoom to more than 100% etc. because they're near sighted, won't be able to enlarge the font and read what you intend for them.

That being said, when there is truly a need for that (and I'm not innocent in this regard either) a somewhat satisfying solutions is simple.

Use font size with respect to screen size, but it's probably best to do so only on big screens.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    element {
        /* font-size: 2.5vh; */
        font-size: 2.5vw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using pixels for the font size.